# Iterate and concatenate over two lists with different lengths while excluding keywords

Tags: python

I have a list which contains multiple lists that have different lengths. I want to delete the element that contains a certain strings and then merge the remaining of the list into a dataframe.

For example, below is the sample code:

```
list1 = ['I have a dream', 'I have a pencile', 'This is a test']
list2 = ['I found a new theory', 'Come here', 'You have a phone', 'This is not right']
listoflist = [list1, list2]
```

I want to iterate `listoflist`, delete the elements that contain the string 'have', concatenate list1 to a dataframe by adding a '|' sign. The final output is something like

```
list1 = ['This is a test']
list2 = ['I found a new theory', 'Come here', 'This is not right']
listoflist = [list1, list2]

# do something...

['This is a test|I found a new theory', 'This is a test|Come here', 'This is a test|This is not right']
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't address string replacement issue.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

final_list = []
for value in (i for pair in zip_longest(listoflist[0], listoflist[1]) for i in pair if i):
    if value > 0:
        final_list.append(value)
    else:
        final_list.insert(0, value)
```

Comment: Do you want a Dataframe as output?

Comment: why is your output list separated by pipes and not by comas ?

Comment: Why is there a zip? Why you compare `value` as number, while it's(?) a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so with some simple list comprehensions:

```
>>> l1 = [i for i in list1 if 'have' not in i]
>>> l2 = [i for i in list2 if 'have' not in i]
>>> l1
['This is a test']

>>> l2
['I found a new theory', 'Come here', 'This is not right']

>>> final = ['|'.join((i, j)) for i in l1 for j in l2]
>>> final
['This is a test|I found a new theory', 'This is a test|Come here', 'This is a test|This is not right']
```

If you have multiple words you want to test, you can try this:

```
excluded = {'theory', 'have'}
l1 = [i for i in list1 if not excluded & set(i.split(' '))]
l2 = [i for i in list2 if not excluded & set(i.split(' '))]
```

This uses the [`set` intersection operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) to check whether the excluded `set` is in any of the words (converted into a `set`, splitted by space.)

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to exclude elements that have both 'have' and 'theory'?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an alternative for multiple checks.

Answer (score 1):

I made some assumptions as your example isn't great.

1. You want to iterate the elements of `listoflist` on top of `listoflist` to remove the string where `have` is present. Since I didn't assume `have` would be in lower case, I used the `lower()` method.
2. `['I found a new theory'| 'Come here'| 'This is not right']` This can not exist in python. You can not have a list-like with elements separated by |. Thus, I chose to create a string output in which a unique concatenated string is created.

```
    list1 = ['I have a dream', 'I have a pencile', 'This is a test']
    list2 = ['I found a new theory', 'Come here', 'You have a phone', 'This is not right']
    listoflist = [list1, list2]

    str_output = []
    for l in listoflist:
        str_output.append("|".join([elt for elt in l if "have" not in elt.lower()]))
```

Output:

```
['This is a test', 'I found a new theory|Come here|This is not right']
```